# how to install ruby on Big Sur

Tags: ruby, macos

Due to the age of my MacBook Pro, the most recent operating system I can update to is Big Sur, 11.7.2 (this is the OS the Apple Store genius bar installed for me today). After getting the new OS, I installed a compatible version of the command line tools (12.2). Now, I have tried to install several versions of Ruby using rbenv and they all failed to build.

Trying to install the latest (3.3.0) I got this error,

```
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/lib/app_provider.c:10:
In file included from apps/include/apps.h:13:
In file included from include/internal/e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/lib/app_params.c:10:
In file included from apps/include/apps.h:13:
In file included from include/internal/e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/lib/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/include/apps.h:13:
In file included from include/internal/e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
```

Trying to install a version (2.7.2) that I thought might be compatiable based on the release of my OS and the command line tools, I get this error

```
apps/bf_prefix.c:10:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
apps/apps.c:18:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/opt.c:9:
In file included from apps/apps.h:13:
In file included from ./e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:243:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
```

My version of clang

```
clang version 5.0.0 (trunk 300079)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

HOw can I install a more recent version of Ruby other than what comes with the system?

```
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
```

UPDATE

full rbenv log for installing ruby 3.3.0

```
rbenv install 3.3.0
==> Downloading openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz...
-> curl -q -fL -o openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/840af5366ab9b522bde525826be3ef0fb0af81c6a9ebd84caa600fea1731eee3
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14.8M  100 14.8M    0     0  25.7M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25.7M
==> Installing openssl-3.1.4...
-> ./config "--prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl" "--openssldir=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/ssl" zlib-dynamic no-ssl3 shared
-> make -j 4

BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.7.2 on x86_64 using ruby-build 20240119-2-g28d59ac)

You can inspect the build directory at /var/folders/5y/wtzzmjlj5v52pg7wr8ptbg_m0000gp/T/ruby-build.20240220103938.12604.Ma5Elp
See the full build log at /var/folders/5y/wtzzmjlj5v52pg7wr8ptbg_m0000gp/T/ruby-build.20240220103938.12604.log
Michaels-MacBook-Pro-3:~ mm$ cat /var/folders/5y/wtzzmjlj5v52pg7wr8ptbg_m0000gp/T/ruby-build.20240220103938.12604.log
cd /var/folders/5y/wtzzmjlj5v52pg7wr8ptbg_m0000gp/T/ruby-build.20240220103938.12604.Ma5Elp
==> Downloading openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz...
-> curl -q -fL -o openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/840af5366ab9b522bde525826be3ef0fb0af81c6a9ebd84caa600fea1731eee3
-> tar xzf openssl-3.1.4.tar.gz
cd /var/folders/5y/wtzzmjlj5v52pg7wr8ptbg_m0000gp/T/ruby-build.20240220103938.12604.Ma5Elp/openssl-3.1.4
==> Installing openssl-3.1.4...
-> ./config "--prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl" "--openssldir=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/ssl" zlib-dynamic no-ssl3 shared
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.1.4 for target darwin64-x86_64
Using os-specific seed configuration
Created configdata.pm
Running configdata.pm
Created Makefile.in
Created Makefile
Created include/openssl/configuration.h

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL.md file first)      ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
-> make -j 4
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/crypto/bn_conf.h.in > include/crypto/bn_conf.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/crypto/dso_conf.h.in > include/crypto/dso_conf.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/asn1.h.in > include/openssl/asn1.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/asn1t.h.in > include/openssl/asn1t.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/bio.h.in > include/openssl/bio.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/cmp.h.in > include/openssl/cmp.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/cms.h.in > include/openssl/cms.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/conf.h.in > include/openssl/conf.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/crmf.h.in > include/openssl/crmf.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/crypto.h.in > include/openssl/crypto.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ct.h.in > include/openssl/ct.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/err.h.in > include/openssl/err.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ess.h.in > include/openssl/ess.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/fipskey.h.in > include/openssl/fipskey.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/lhash.h.in > include/openssl/lhash.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ocsp.h.in > include/openssl/ocsp.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslv.h.in > include/openssl/opensslv.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/pkcs12.h.in > include/openssl/pkcs12.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/pkcs7.h.in > include/openssl/pkcs7.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/safestack.h.in > include/openssl/safestack.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/srp.h.in > include/openssl/srp.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ssl.h.in > include/openssl/ssl.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/ui.h.in > include/openssl/ui.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/x509.h.in > include/openssl/x509.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/x509_vfy.h.in > include/openssl/x509_vfy.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" include/openssl/x509v3.h.in > include/openssl/x509v3.h
perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" "-oMakefile" test/provider_internal_test.cnf.in > test/provider_internal_test.cnf
make depend && make _build_sw
clang  -I. -Iinclude -Iapps/include  -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/ossl-modules\"" -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.d.tmp -MT apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o -c -o apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o apps/lib/app_libctx.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -Iapps/include  -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/ossl-modules\"" -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_params.d.tmp -MT apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_params.o -c -o apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_params.o apps/lib/app_params.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -Iapps/include  -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/ossl-modules\"" -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_provider.d.tmp -MT apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_provider.o -c -o apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_provider.o apps/lib/app_provider.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -Iapps/include  -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/Users/mm/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/openssl/lib/ossl-modules\"" -D_REENTRANT -DOPENSSL_BUILDING_OPENSSL -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG  -MMD -MF apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_rand.d.tmp -MT apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_rand.o -c -o apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_rand.o apps/lib/app_rand.c
In file included from apps/lib/app_libctx.c:9:
In file included from apps/include/app_libctx.h:13:
In file included from include/openssl/types.h:32:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
In file included from /usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
apps/lib/app_provider.c:10:
In file included from apps/include/apps.h:13:
In file included from include/internal/e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/lib/app_rand.c:10:
In file included from apps/include/apps.h:13:
In file included from include/internal/e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from apps/lib/app_params.c:10:
In file included from apps/include/apps.h:13:
In file included from include/internal/e_os.h:16:
In file included from include/openssl/e_os2.h:234:
/usr/local/lib/clang/5.0.0/include/inttypes.h:30:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_params.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_provider.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_rand.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_libctx.o] Error 1
make: *** [build_sw] Error 2
external command failed with status 2
```

Comment: Can you post the full log from `rbenv`?

Comment: @engineersmnky see update in OP

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this sort of error occurs when there are missing dependencies. Make sure you have the latest Xcode Command Line Tools installed before you install ruby.

You can update them using the following command:

`xcode-select --install`

Comment: I have the version of the command line tools installed that is compatible with my OS (Big Sur), and which should be compatible, based on the date of release, with ruby 2.7.2.   But xcode itself is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

telling rbenv to use a different clang (i.e. not the one in /usr/local/bin)  solved the issue

> CC=/usr/bin/clang rbenv install 3.3.0 now